# How do I setup Xerox Workcentre 3025 printing (over network/wifi)?

Tags: printing, 21.04, xerox

Choosing any of the available Xerox drivers in the cups printer setup doesn't make it possible for me to use the Xerox Workcentre 3025 printer (over network/wifi) for printing.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

A working solution turned out to be using a generic driver available as a samsung unified driver from https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ ("Generic IPP Everywhere Printer").

I've added the sources:

```
# fgrep -i suldr -r /etc/apt
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/ debian extra
```

and installed:

```
suld-driver-common-1
suld-ppd-2
suldr-keyring
```

and configured the printer in cups, and now it works.

The installed packages are (as shown by `apt-cache showpkg`):

```
Package: suld-driver-common-1
Versions: 
1-13 (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages
                  MD5: 2a69eb024131df591e4811bd635a7797


Reverse Depends: 
  suld-driver-3.00.37,suld-driver-common-1
  suld-driver-4.01.17,suld-driver-common-1
  suld-driver-4.00.39,suld-driver-common-1
  suld-driver-3.00.65,suld-driver-common-1
Dependencies: 
1-13 - debconf (16 (null)) debconf-2.0 (0 (null)) suldr-keyring (0 (null)) suld-driver-common-install (0 (null)) suld-driver2-common-install (0 (null)) suld-driver-common-install (0 (null)) suld-driver2-common-install (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
1-13 - suld-driver-common-1:i386 (= 1-13) suld-driver-common-install (= ) 
Reverse Provides: 
Package: suld-ppd-2
Versions: 
4.01.17-5 (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages
                  MD5: b45c991b99125932080c08d8d7c243fb


Reverse Depends: 
  suld-driver-4.01.17,suld-ppd-2
Dependencies: 
4.01.17-5 - suld-ppd-install (0 (null)) suld-ppd-install (0 (null)) 
Provides: 
4.01.17-5 - suld-ppd-2:i386 (= 4.01.17-5) suld-ppd-install (= ) 
Reverse Provides: 
Package: suldr-keyring
Versions: 
2 (/var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/www.bchemnet.com_suldr_dists_debian_extra_binary-all_Packages
                  MD5: a06ff8ef891b345bfdc8997a518bd8cc


Reverse Depends: 
  suld-driver-common-1,suldr-keyring
  suld-driver2-common-1,suldr-keyring
Dependencies: 
2 - gnupg (2 1.0.6-4) 
Provides: 
2 - 
Reverse Provides: 
root@versace-GP:~#
```